# How do I change a SharePoint 2007's URL

Tags: sharepoint, url

I created a new SharePoint portal for testing purposes using a manually added HOSTS record.  I have it all tested and want to expose it to the outside world using a URL from our DNS.

I can't seem to find a straight forward way to change the URL of a SharePoint portal.  Does anyone know where this setting is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.  I found the answer at:

http://www.sharepointblogs.com/johnwpowell/archive/2007/01/04/how-to-change-the-sharepoint-url-using-alternate-access-mappings.aspx

Comment: Congratz :) Don't forget that Alternate Access Mapping is linked to each of your site collection which can have different urls for public/intranet/extranet.